# Как сделать прием данных из фаербэйс?

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Дано**
Код адаптера SwipeCard, Активити куда встроен SwipeCard  и xml файлы

**Цель**
Загрузить в shapeableimageview фото и имя с нужной папки firebase real-time data base.

**Проблема**
Загрузка не происходит

```
Адаптер java class
```

```
    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> list;


    public SwipeAdapter(Context context,List<Integer>list) {
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view;
     if(convertView==null)
     {
         view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_koloda,parent,false);

     }else {
         view=convertView;
     }
     return view;
    }
   
}
```

Активити с кодом получения данных

```
private SwipeAdapter adapter;
private List<Integer> list;
private TextView nameusercard;
private ShapeableImageView imageosnovnoe;
Koloda koloda;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        koloda=findViewById(R.id.koloda);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new SwipeAdapter(this,list);
        koloda.setAdapter(adapter);
        nameusercard=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameusercard);
        imageosnovnoe=(ShapeableImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageosnovnoe);


    }
private void getUsermenwomInfo()
{
    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Userw");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)
            {
                String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                nameusercard.setText(name);
                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                    String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageosnovnoe);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Xml  файл item koloda с свайпером

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageosnovnoe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                app:srcCompat="@drawable/aaaaa" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearhori"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/sas"



                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/disslike"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/aan"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>




    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: под отладкой пробовали посмотреть что происходит? есть ли в базе картинка, что пишет в логах?

Comment: В базе есть несколько папок которые содержат картинку,имя и uid я их и прописал как те откуда надо принимать. Лог смотрел ошибок вроде нет

Comment: а вы пробовали другие способы получения картинки за пределами приложения? постманом например или просто по урл, если есть доступ

Comment: Нет, я вообще о них не знал до этого момента.я же новичок вопрос скорее всего для вас глупый но мне действительно это не понятно и я буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Comment: По  Url работает.

Comment: посмотрите какой адрес вы получаете в приложении, и доступен ли imageview для picasso

Comment: А как это можно посмотреть?

Comment: через логи например https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat, или через отладку вот так https://developer.android.com/studio/debug